# How to Understand "Pass By Reference Within a Function" w3schools example?

Tags: c++, function, reference, swap

I'm having a hard time understanding how this example from the w3schools tutorial works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapNums(int &x, int &y) {
  int z = x;
  x = y;
  y = z;
}

int main() {
  int firstNum = 10;
  int secondNum = 20;

  cout << "Before swap: " << "\n";
  cout << firstNum << secondNum << "\n";

  // Call the function, which will change the values of firstNum and secondNum
  swapNums(firstNum, secondNum);

  cout << "After swap: " << "\n";
  cout << firstNum << secondNum << "\n";

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I think I understand the first part:

```
void swapNums(int &x, int &y) {
  int z = x;
  x = y;
  y = z;
}
```

I'm basically referencing whatever `x` and `y` are going to be when I call the function. So `x` is going to be "pointing" to `firstNum` and `y` is going to be pointing to `secondNum`. It's going to do the switcheroo using a third variable as a placeholder.

However, after I call the function `swapNums(firstNum, secondNum);`, I don't understand how the function with its local variables has the ability to change the values of `int firstNum = 10;` and `int secondNum = 20;`.
My understanding is that variables within a function are "local" and the scope of said variables only extend within the function itself. How do the local variables change other variables outside their own function without any return statements?

Comment: The part you're missing is the entire point of the program. The parameters to the function are taken *by reference* instead of by value. They refer to the original variables. Meaning changes to the function parameters are, in fact, changes to the original variables. When the function is finished, the parameters do go away, but they're only references, so the *references* go away. You're mixing principles. You learned about scope and locality and pass-by-value parameters. Now you're learning about pass-by-reference parameters.

Comment: "So x is going to be "pointing" to firstNum and y is going to be pointing to secondNum" replace "pointing to" with "refereces" and you have the answer. `x` refers to `firstNum` and `y` refers to `secondNum`. `x` and `y` are local to the function, but whatever you to do `x` and `y`, you are actually doing to `firstNum` and `secondNum`.

Comment: A way of thinking about references is : They are pointers that MUST have a valid address (they cannot be nullptr) and they can't be changed (not even accidentally). And you don't have to worry about memory management (like if I get a pointer from someone do I need to delete it or will they delete it), references are only there to be used. So in a way they're a safer version of pointers really. And as a bonus you can use const references, telling a function not to change the value: the benefit if it is a reference to a class it will not be copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

void change_val_by_ref(int &x)
{
    x=100
}

void change_val_by_val(int x)
{
    x=50;
}
int main()
{
    int whatever=0;
    std::cout<<"Original value: "<<whatever<<"\n";
    change_val_by_ref(whatever);
    std::cout<<"After change by ref: "<<whatever<<"\n";
    change_val_by_val(whatever);
    std::cout<<"After change by val: "<<whatever<<"\n";
}
```

The output you will see is:

```
0
100
100
```

Let's see what happened

- `change_val_by_ref` changed the original `whatever`, because the ref
  was "pointing" to the VARIABLE.
- `change_val_by_val` didn't change the `whatever`, because the argument of the function `x` has just copied the value of `whatever`, and anything that happens to `x` will not affect `whatever`, because they are not related.

That's the point of passing by ref.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have banana and orange placed in two different plates. You place them into big box with a robotic hand.
You, obviously, can change their destination using you hand. But you want the robotic hand to do this task. You need to tell where the banana and orange are placed, so robotic hand can do its job. !Important robotic hand doesn't care about fruit, which is placed into these plates, it only cares about changing their positions.
By using a pointer, you just tell a function the placement of an object you want to change. And you can set your local, suitable name for this. So pointer is just the name of a plate, which contains a certain value.

Comment: I don't think this is helpful in understanding how C++, specifically, handles pointers and references.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

References are syntactic sugar for passing around addresses of variables. Instead of the variable itself, you pass its memory address and then the function uses the address of the variable to change its value. Simple as that.   Equivalent C code would be:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
  int tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: "*References are syntactic sugar for passing around addresses of variables*" - technically, the standard only says that references are just aliases to objects, nothing more. How references are implemented is up to the compiler vendors. Though, MOST compilers implement references as pointers, which hold memory addresses. But the standard does not dictate that behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, of course. I was trying to give a mental model. At the end of the day, a flat memory model itself is an abstraction.